# how to download and install all node modules through package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I want to invoke and download all node modules through maven, in maven I have defined the plugins to install it but now in my package.json i have defined the following npm install command, please advise how can i install all node modules and can define them in package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
   "author": "Saral",
  "scripts":{
  "start":"node gulpfile.js",
   "prebuild": "npm install",
    "build": "gulp"
    },

  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "*",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "*",
    "gulp-util": "*",
    "gulp-rename": "*",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-concat-vendor": "0.0.4",
    "map-stream": "*",
    "gulp-livereload": "*",
    "gulp-concat": "*",
    "gulp-uglify": "*",
    "gulp-minify-css" : "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-notify":"2.2.0",
    "gulp-inject": "1.5.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.4",
    "stream-series": "0.1.1",
    "gulp-gzip": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-clone": "1.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "*"


  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Go to your terminal and type in

```
npm install
```

This will crawl through all the required packages mentioned in package.json and download it to node_modules folder.

When using gulp in your gulpfile.js

```
var install = require("gulp-install");

gulp.src(['./bower.json', './package.json'])
.pipe(install());
```

So when you run gulp in your terminal all the packages in bower.json and package.json will be downloaded into bower_components and node_modules, respectively.

Comment: Thanks I agree to this but i want to install it through package.json only please advise can i achieve these thriugh package.json also

Comment: your question is not clear. you want to install packages through package.json? npm install functionality is to read package.json and install using npm registry.

Comment: well if i do my changes then i do not want every one to install node modules folder manually can i configure it such that when some one run maven then all node modules folder will be downloaded

Comment: you mean to automate the process of downloading the required modules for a project? using maven or gulp

Comment: Yes please advise, can I use maven to download all node modules

Comment: I have automated package install using gulp but in your case you need to do that using maven. I guess this link would be able to help you out https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: Pls share gulp one also

Comment: Thanks a lot but what about if gulp package is dependent upon other packages , I also want to download dependent packages and also I won't mind downloading all packages of node module please advise how to achieve that also

Comment: dependency of packages is all handled by npm. you don't need to worry about that. if in case you want to micro-manage the packages. please go through npm documentation which will open doors to peer-dependencies and all other sorts of dependencies available in npm.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, just use the "[Frontend Maven Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)"

1. It installs node & npm: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installing-node-and-npm
2. Executes `npm install`, which is already the default argument and can be omitted: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#running-npm